# Hot to Wait.until not a string in a text_field, with Watir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

I want that Watir waits until the text in a text_field disappear, or be replaced. But, when I try to do like this:

```
Watir::Wait.until { browser.text_field(:id, "ContentPlaceHolder").value =! "textExample" }
```

it keeps printing the string "false" in the text field repeatedly.

How can I make this whait until there is no the textExample in the text_field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem with your code is the

```
value =! "textExample"
```

Notice that you have a `=!`. I believe this is actually saying assign the *not* of "textExample", which is false. So really you are saying to assign false to the text field.

**Solution 0 - Fix =!**

If you fix the typo of `=!` to be `!=`, it should work:

```
Watir::Wait.until { browser.text_field(:id, "ContentPlaceHolder").value != "textExample" }
```

**Solution 1 - Using wait_until**

While your code will work with the fixed typo. I do not believe the recommendation is to use Watir::Wait directly. You should use the built in `wait_until` method instead.

```
browser.wait_until{ browser.text_field(:id, "ContentPlaceHolder").value != "textExample" }
```

or use `wait_while` (depending on your reading preferences)

```
browser.wait_while{ browser.text_field(:id, "ContentPlaceHolder").value == "textExample" }
```

**Solution 2 - Using wait_while_present**

Alternatively, you might want to use the `Element#wait_while_present` method.

Try doing:

```
browser.text_field(:id => "ContentPlaceHolder", :text => "textExample").wait_while_present
```

Comment: Actually, I was using !=, but it didn't worked too, so I tried =!, and submited here with the last one.

Your browser.wait_while should have solved my problem!

I just made it with the simple correction of a to_s:
    Watir::Wait.until { browser.text_field(:id, "ContentPlaceHolder").value.to_S != "textExample" }

Anyway, thank you!